# Exclude or negate tag in Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, tags, ignored-tags

Suppose I want to ask a question regarding CSS, but I keep getting answers with JavaScript alternatives. I'd love to be able do something like

Tags: [CSS] -[JavaScript]

And most importantly,

Tags: [JavaScript] -[jQuery]

Comment: i hope you know how voting works in meta

Answer (score 7):

I think you may misunderstand the intended purpose of tags: they are supposed to be used to categorize questions but do not necessarily dictate the *precise* technologies that the question's answers must have. If you want an answer that uses CSS and not JavaScript—or JavaScript and not jQuery—just say so in your question.

Comment: Oh, I was just annoyed how some people insist on providing solutions in jQuery even when the asker specifically stated they need it in pure Javascript. And the worst part is that the jQuery answer gets a lot of up votes. Its completely ridiculous.

Comment: @caleb I can definitely sympathize with your frustration, but to be fair, [jQuery *is* kind of special...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/162705)

Comment: yeap, it makes life quite simple for most of the more complex things we like to do in Javascript, but honestly, i prefer not to load that ridiculously large library when a very clean and simple solution is required.

Answer (score 2):

The point of those answers is to help the community in general. Although some might use them to show you how much they know even though you don't need it.

The type of answers you get also depends on the title of your question and its specificity. Just mention that you do not want javascript solutions to this question in the description. In short, with the current system, you can handle this situation.

Moreover, excluding a tag sometimes removes the possibility of having good answers which could help others. Of course you dont come here to solve others problems but that is a price of society.

Answer (score 0):

Tags are not applied to answers, only questions. This can't be done.

Just leave a note in your question asking specifically what you want, and downvote the answers that do not conform.

Comment: I agree with down-voting; if I explicitly ask for a solution that is not using jQuery, the answer that suggest using it is not helpful for me. I understand that nowadays is quite easy to get jQuery, especially in some frameworks/CMS's, but there could be a good reason I am asking for a solution not involving jQuery.